# Скопировать часть объекта BitmapData

Tags: flash, actionscript, bitmap

Цель такова: Разделить MovieClip на 16 частей, и каждую положить в соответствующую ячейку двоичного массива.
Для этого перегоняю MovieClip в BitmapData  и там пытаюсь отделить нужную часть.
**Почему-то всё вырезается из верхнего левого угла исходной картинки** 
[вот так](http://www.meduzo.ru/pics/f38c7640315b51ca80153d981a3e1b25.png)

```
private function update (event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        gameArray = new Array();
        for (var i: uint = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            gameArray[i] = new Array();
            for (var j: uint = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                gameArray[i][j] = new MovieClip();
                var X:int = 100 * i;
                var Y:int = 100 * j;
                var bit:BitmapData = new BitmapData(mc.width / 4, mc.height / 4, false, 0xffffff);
                var tempData:BitmapData = cropBitmap(bit, 100, 100, X, Y);
                var tempBitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(tempData);
                tempData.draw(mc);

                gameArray[i][j].x = X;
                gameArray[i][j].y = Y;
                gameArray[i][j].addChild(tempBitmap);
                addChild(gameArray[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    private function cropBitmap(bmd:BitmapData, newWidth:uint, newHeight:uint, newX:uint, newY:uint):BitmapData
    {
        var newBMD:BitmapData = new BitmapData(newWidth, newHeight);
        newBMD.copyPixels(bmd, new Rectangle(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight), new Point(newX, newY));
        //также пытался:  
         //new Rectangle(newX, newY, newWidth, newHeight), new Point(0, 0)
         //new Rectangle(newX, newY, newWidth, newHeight), new Point(newX, newY)
        return newBMD;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался в чем дело.

```
private function update (event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        //нужно было определять область, из которой копировать данные здесь
        var bit:BitmapData = new BitmapData(mc.width, mc.height);
        bit.draw(mc);

        gameArray = new Array();
        for (var i: uint = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            gameArray[i] = new Array();
            for (var j: uint = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                gameArray[i][j] = new MovieClip();
                var X:int = 100 * i;
                var Y:int = 100 * j;

                var tempData:BitmapData = cropBitmap(bit, 100, 100, X, Y);
                var tempBitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(tempData);

                gameArray[i][j].x = X;
                gameArray[i][j].y = Y;
                gameArray[i][j].addChild(tempBitmap);
                addChild(gameArray[i][j]);

            }
        }

    }

    private function cropBitmap(bmd:BitmapData, newWidth:uint, newHeight:uint, newX:uint, newY:uint):BitmapData
    {
        var newBMD:BitmapData = new BitmapData(newWidth, newHeight);
          //rect определяет область, которую нужно вырезать
        var rect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(newX, newY, newWidth, newHeight); 
        var pnt:Point = new Point(0, 0);  //pnt определяет, сколько пикселей будет 
                                          //отрезанно верхней и нижней или
                                          //правой и левой границы соответственно

        newBMD.copyPixels(bmd, rect, pnt);

        return newBMD;
    }
```